# How is 'hard work' considered a noun?

Tags: nouns

An excerpt from my grammar lesson:

> In a formal context, 'due' should always be treated as an adjective, and 'due to' must therefore follow or refer back to a noun, as in: his success was due to hard work.

In this case, how is 'hard work' considered a noun? In a prior lesson, a noun was defined as *a word that names a person, place or thing.* by this definition, isn't 'hard work' more appropriate to be a verb?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something! "Hard work" is a noun phrase headed by the common noun "work" which is modified by the adjective "hard". Note that a noun phrase can also consist of a single noun, as in "My favourite food is **fish**." "Work" is an abstract noun ,as opposed to a concrete noun like "car","house", "gin" and the like.

Comment: [Work](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/work) is noun or verb. Sadly your definition of [noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun) isn't accurate. Wikipedia's definition is slightly better: "a word that generally functions as the name of a specific object or set of objects, such as living creatures, places, **actions**, qualities, states of existence, or ideas" but it's best to think in terms of grammatical categories (a noun is a subject or object of a verb, etc). Don't they have nouns and verbs in your native language, though?

Comment: @BillJ - many sources advise that a phrase is 'a group of two or more words that express a single idea but do not usually form a complete sentence', The OED 2nd Ed provides 'Applied to a single word. Obs.' with the latest quote dated 1699.

Comment: Nothing in the explanation says it can't be a noun preceded by an adjective....

Comment: @Crissy Note also that "due to" is not a phrase. The adjective "due" licenses a to preposition phrase , as in "due to hard work", where "hard work" is a noun phrase  (headed by the abstract noun "work") functioning as object of the prep "to".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey BillJ used the term "noun phrase", which is a term that can include just one word. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phrase) says: "4 : **a word** or group of words forming a syntactic constituent with a single grammatical function -- *an adverbial phrase*"

Answer (score 1):

Many regard single word nouns as constituting noun phrases. A problem area is with open compounds, where the debate can become heated. But your worry about 'hard work' would be unfounded were it legitimate:

- *His continued success was due to hard work.*

has two noun groups and is uncontroversial.

But note that the rule states

'due to' must therefore **follow** / **refer back** to a noun [group; noun / noun phrase]:

it's [*his*] *success* that should be being asked about (it's fine).

................

There is, however, a real problem with the 'rule'. The modern trend is to allow the broader 'because of' sense of 'due to'. Not just the 'caused by' sense, which requires a noun phrase whose referent is the thing caused. From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/due-to):

> **due to** [phrase]: because of:
>
> 1. A lot of her unhappiness is due to boredom.
> 2. The bus was delayed due to heavy snow.
> 3. Regrettably, the service has been dropped due to lack of funding.
> 4. The series was cancelled due to poor ratings.
> 5. Processing is inevitably slower due to increased security measures.

Only the first example they feel happy to endorse is of the form the 'rule' allows,

[Noun Phrase] [form of *be*] [due to] [Noun Phrase].

The remaining examples, quite idiomatic nowadays, are of the form

[Independent clause] [due to] [Noun Phrase].

Those who forbid such sentences are over-prescriptivist.

Comment: But "due to" is not a phrase. The adjective "due" licenses a _to_ PP, as in the OP's "due to hard work", where "hard work" is an NP (headed by the abstract noun "work") functioning as object of the prep "to".

Comment: The bracketing is [due + [to + NP]] , where the inner brackets enclose a PP with an NP complement.

Answer (score -1):

A mod seems to have deleted a salient comment I posted when voting to migrate this question from ELU to ELL. Specifically...

> *"a word that names a person, place or thing"* is a [***proper noun***](https://www.scribbr.co.uk/nouns/proper-noun/)

Proper nouns are *always* written with an initial capital letter.  Some proper nouns can also be used as an "ordinary" noun. So ***Trump*** is a proper noun referring to the ex-president, but ***trump*** can refer to the "primary" playing card suit in various card games.

***Hard work*** is a [***noun phrase***](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/what-is-a-noun-phrase-in-english) - *a word or group of words that can function as the subject, the object, or the complement in a sentence.* The "head" noun there is ***work***, modified by the adjective ***hard***, which gives some more information about the specific work being referenced. Example usage...

> 1: *Being a coal miner is **hard work***

---

Note that ***work*** can also be used as a ***verb***. And ***to work hard*** is a ***verb phrase*** where the adverb ***hard*** modifies the verb. For example...

> 2: *You have to **work hard** as a coal miner*

Comment: I can't tell how proper nouns relate to the rest of your answer, or to the question (instead of just ordinary nouns). Could you explain that connection more?

Comment: Proper nouns *don;t* relate to much about either the question or my answer. The OP was using an inappropriate term, that's all.

Comment: *Always* is always dangerous, @FumbleFingers. As a pen name (of Gloria Jean Watkins), *bell hooks* is a proper noun, and she was emphatic about its being styled in all-lower case.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: Well, as a general principle I'm not much interested in "the naming of the parts". Nobody taught me anything about parts of speech, clauses, numbered conditionals, etc. - but that didn't stop me getting an honours degree in (English and French) Language and Literature. But the "proper noun" definition in my link was almost word-for-word what OP cited as the definition of a (regular) noun, so it made sense to point that out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm glad I'm not the only person who types `don;t`

Comment: It only happens on my [Logitech K810](https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/140683599) keyboard - imho streets ahead of everything else for a "home entertainment" PC (lights up when you put your hand near it, good key action, battery lasts ages,...). But I live up to my handle here, so I keep mishitting because the keys are *slightly* closer together than the Logitech MX Keys keyboard i use for programming. At least it's easy to disable the Caps Lock key, which was also a problem until I found out how to do that!

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: **e e cummings** is unquestionably a proper noun, and there's never been any confusion about the capitalisation there. But anyone who's aware of such "non-compliant outliers" is unlikely to be reading my text here in order to learn what exactly a proper noun is. And if they *do* need to learn it (as clearly the OP himself here did), it's only sensible that I should mention ***always*** capitalised, since that's what my linked definition says (rather gratifyingly, ***with BrE spelling**!* :)

Comment: Actually, @FumbleFingers, I guess you should never say *never* either. It would appear that you are confused about [the capitalization there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._E._Cummings#Name_and_capitalization) :-). In any event, I meant only to have a bit of fun with you about your (technically) over-generalized generalization with *always*.

Comment: Fascinating! Wikipedia says *Harry T. Moore notes Cummings "had his name put legally into lower case, and in his later books the titles and his name were always in lower case". According to Cummings' widow, however, this is incorrect. She wrote to Friedman: "You should not have allowed H. Moore to make such a stupid & childish statement about Cummings & his signature."* What *really* intrigues me is that the man's wife until his death should refer to him by his *surname!* That's just too bizarre! I don't believe *her* story, though. She sounds away with the fairies.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I would do that more often, if I were not using an Italian-layout keyboard. (American-layout keyboards gave me more troubles.)

Comment: (With an Italian keyboard, I could rather write `don?t`, if I do not correctly press the shift key.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I never did it much before I got a [Cherry Stream](https://www.techradar.com/reviews/cherry-stream-desktop-keyboard-and-mouse-combo) keyboard. It's otherwise lovely to type on. My wife says it's the best keyboard she has ever used. It's also very quiet.